# Is the order of records in a VALUES list well-defined (postgres)?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Postgres 9.4 introduced the WITH ORDINALITY clause which adds an ordinality column to a table-like expression, somewhat similar to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()`. Apparently, this is used to provide ranks for set-returning functions like `unnest(<array>)`. My question is, is the order of rows defined for VALUES lists? I would like very much for this to be the case:

```
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')) xs(a);
 a | row_number 
---+------------
 a |          1
 b |          2
 c |          3
```

EDIT: Fixed to use ROW_NUMBER instead of WITH ORDINALITY (which is syntactically incompatible with a values list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VALUES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) is treated like SELECT. The [SELECT documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#id-1.9.3.171.7) says:

> 8. If the `ORDER BY` clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in the specified order. If `ORDER BY` is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.

Your version of Postgres happens to return the three rows in the order you have written them. While unlikely, this could change in the future.